# how to place the imagekey to the right side of the listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I am trying to add an imagekey to my items and it works fine except that the image 

 appears on the leftside of the listview in vb.net. 

 What I am trying to do is have it appear on the right side or in another column,

 but I can't seem to do that.

can anyone help?

Thanks

 Gibit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to have an image in some other column when the listview is in Detail mode. You can't do that in the standard .NET listview control by default. I believe you would need to override a bunch of drawing-related events and possibly deal with some Win32 calls to have images show in subitems.

However, there is an open source custom listview control for .NET called [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) that supports this feature. You could use that instead of the built-in one.

Comment: Yup that is exactly what i want to do. Cool Thx, I will give that a try